# Rails 3: javascript_include_tag :all - what's it do exactly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

first off what's the difference between

```
javascript_include_tag :all
```

and

```
javascript_include_tag :defaults
```

Lastly, I previously had this code:

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js', 'application.js' , 'jquery.tokeninput.js', 'rails.validations.js'  %>`

Which didn't load my js right for example jquery.tokeninput.js wasn't working at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code: `javascript_include_tag :all` loads all JavaScript files from /public/ or /assets/javascript folder

And the code: `javascript_include_tag :defaults` includes only "default" set of JavaScript files configured in config/application.rb file.

By default those are application.js, rails.js, prototype.js (or jQuery depending of which is turned on) and few more.